# sbcl note "could not stack allocate"

Tags: sorting, stack, common-lisp, sbcl

Why is sbcl (2.0.11) giving these compiler notes? Does it mean that this is not an efficient approach? Is there something you can do to stack allocate the predicate and key? Or is another approach better?

```lisp
(defun sort-on-car (x)
  (sort x #'> :key #'car))
```

```
; in: DEFUN SORT-ON-CAR
;     (SORT PLAGE::X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::PREDICATE-FUN in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::KEY in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::PREDICATE-FUN in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::KEY in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 4 notes
```

Minimal reproducible example, provided on request. The file contains only the function definition above.

```
$ /usr/bin/sbcl --no-sysinit --no-userinit
This is SBCL 2.0.11, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (compile-file "/tmp/sortwarning.lisp")
; compiling file "/tmp/sortwarning.lisp" (written 13 JAN 2021 09:50:06 AM):
; processing (DEFUN SORT-ON-CAR ...)
; file: /tmp/sortwarning.lisp
; in: DEFUN SORT-ON-CAR
;     (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::PREDICATE-FUN in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::KEY in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::PREDICATE-FUN in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; note: could not stack allocate SB-IMPL::KEY in: (SORT X #'> :KEY #'CAR)
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 4 notes


; wrote /tmp/sortwarning.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.050
#P"/tmp/sortwarning.fasl"
NIL
NIL
*
```

Comment: This is not reproducable in either SBCL 2.0.11 or 2.1.0 as best I can see.  Can you provide a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: Question edited to add minimal reporducable example. Running on Arch Linux.

Comment: I have tried this exact thing with 2.1.0 (and 2.0.11 yesterday bu I no longer have that): I can only guess that your `/usr/bin/sbcl` (or the image it uses) is somehow broken (because I have no idea how these message could happen).  Have you tried a clean install from [sbcl.org](http://www.sbcl.org/)?

Comment: Clean install version ```2.1.0.43-8b5f058b5``` gives the same behaviour.

Comment: OK, I have no idea: your environment must be strange in some way as SBCL doesn't say this for me (and I can't even see what would persuade it to say that: what on earth is it trying to stack allocate and why?)

Comment: I had a poke around in the source code and it does look as if there is stuff which is trying to suppress compiler notes about stack allocation failures, which I guess must be not working somehow.  Have a look at `.../compiler/ir1util.lisp` I think.  I tried to disable this suppression, but I'm not sure if I managed (this was trying to redefine things on top of a running SBCL) and if I did it still would not warn.  I'm not sure if there is an SBCL mailing list but that might be the right place to ask: your code is fine.